# Is it possible to get the Identity value in the ItemInserted event in a listView?

Tags: asp.net

I'd rather not make a call to the database to query @@IDENTITY.  Is there some way to get the identity value for what was just inserted through code?

Comment: I think it would help if you provide information about the type of datasource and data access technic (SqlDataSource? Linq to SQL? Linq to Entities? ObjectDataSource? etc.) you are using with the ListView. The ListView won't know anything about the inserted data on its own since it's fed through a datasource. I guess returning the identity will be a capability of the data source, not of the ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by adding an OnInserted event to my LinqDataSource that my listview was using.  See below:

```
protected void lds_Personnel_OnInserted(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    int id= ((Personnel)e.Result).IdentityNameHere;
.
.
.
}
```

Hope it's helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead.

Comment: My point is that I don't want to query the DB.  Can i get this from code?

Comment: I'm not sure then what you're trying to achieve. If you insert something with an automated Identity column into the DB, then the DB is the only place from where you can retrieve that value. It is common practice thhough to add a SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() call at the end of your INSERT statement, in order to retrieve the idenity value w/o having to query the DB multiple times. This is also the most reliable way to make sure you retrieve the correct ID.

Comment: What I'm wondering is if it is possible to get the Identity value through the ListView event args rather than the database.  I understand that the DB is the source of the Identity, but ListViews often pull these values in automatically.  That's why I can iterate through each item in my ListView and look at the DataKey value.  My question is if there is a way to find the Identity (DataKey) value of a record that I inserted through my list view but have not bound yet.  My end goal is to insert records into a child table using this id from within the ItemInserted event.